# Binding AWS Amplify Datastore to MUI datagrid

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, aws-amplify

I'm using an AWS Amplify Datastore and want to bind the data to an MUI datagrid.

I'm querying the Datastore via:

const stocks = await DataStore.query(Stock)

Result looks like this:

```
Stock {
    id: '7991c45e-4700-4e86-88fd-edc33ef0af8d',
    exchange: 'tsx',
    symbol: 'rei-un',
    alltimehighprice: 100,
    highprice52week: 100,
    lowprice52week: 100,
    currentprice: 100,
    createdAt: '2022-07-01T05:31:26.454Z',
    updatedAt: '2022-07-01T05:31:26.454Z',
    _version: 1,
    _lastChangedAt: 1656653486477,
    _deleted: null
  }

JSON.stringify(stocks) looks like this:

[{"id":"7991c45e-4700-4e86-88fd-edc33ef0af8d","exchange":"tsx","symbol":"rei-un", 
"_version":1,"_lastChangedAt":1656653486477,"_deleted":null}]
```

DataGrid looks like this:

```
import { DataGrid } from '@mui/x-data-grid'

const stocksData = JSON.stringify(stocks);

  <div style={{ height: 400, width: '100%' }}>
    <DataGrid
      rows={stocksData}
      columns={columns}
      id="id"
      pageSize={5}
      rowsPerPageOptions={[5]}
      checkboxSelection
    />
  </div>
```

I've tried passing both "stocks" and JSON.stringify(stocks) as the rows parameter, neither works.

Since JSON.stringify(stocks) returns an array of objects where each object has an id, it appears it should work but I receive the following error:

Error: MUI: The data grid component requires all rows to have a unique `id` property.

The MUI data grid example passes a hardcoded array of objects with an id property very similar to what I am passing.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve using:

```
  const stockData = JSON.stringify(stocks);

  const stockArr = JSON.parse(stockData);
```

and using

```
 <DataGrid rows={stockArr} />
```

It doesn't make sense to me that you need first to stringify and then parse the DataStore query result, but it is working for me now.